# Run one command after another in zsh when Ctrl-C is pressed

Tags: zsh, alias, signals

I have recently moved to `zsh` from `bash` (on OSX).  I have an bash alias I have used to run one program then another (even if previous program exits with error) on bash.  I can't work out how to replicate this in zsh.

bash alias I would like to replicate is:

```
gulp ; say "Gulp has crashed"
```

Does anyone know how to rewrite this in zsh?

#### Edit:

The difference between `zsh` and `bash` I'm getting is that; with Bash pressing `ctrl-c` when gulp is running, stops gulp and then goes on to the next command.

in Zsh pressing `ctrl-c` seems to stop whole command line.

The purpose of my use of this line is to get an audible warning when gulp stops running in the background.  (for non-mac users the say command is a text to speach converter)

Answer (score 4):

I propose to use a function instead:

```
mygulp () { trap : INT; gulp || say "Gulp has crashed"; }
```

The `trap` will catch `Ctrl-C` ("interrupt" signal) and run `:` command (ie. nothing).

Notice also `||` instead of `;` - this way if `gulp` exits normally (you didn't press ctrl-c) then nothing happens, but if exit code is not zero then `say` command will start.

This function should work both in `bash` and `zsh`, in the later you can remove last `;` before closing right bracket.

Comment: Watch out that the trap will still be in place when the function exits. To avoid this portably, use `mygulp () (…)` to run the function code in a subshell. In zsh, alternatively, run `setopt local_traps local_opions` in the function.

Comment: The second option from @Gilles should be `local_options`.